# where condition is not recognizing my full String

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I am using spring and hibernate in my project. This is My Query. When I execute this query I am getting data from DB. But if I frame the query like this I am getting 0 records.

```
String fullname1 = "this is my String";
select name,gender from account where fullname='fullname1';
```

If I create query like this I am getting data. But `fullname1` is not a static data.

```
select name,gender from account where fullname like '%this%';
```

Problem is if my fullname1 is have only one word then I am getting proper data. If it has  multiple words I am not getting data.

Can any one suggest me how to frame query in this situation.

Answer (score -1):

Try to concatenate your string to search like this

```
select name,gender from account where fullname like '%' + yourVariable + '%';
```

Assuming `yourVariable` is containing the string which you want to search.

**EDIT:**

As confirmed by OP in comments the query which worked for him/her is:

```
select name,gender from account where fullname='" + fullname1+ "'";
```

Also your query is prone to SQL Injection. So it is better to use [Prepared statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: Thank q.my problem is solved by using fellowing query.

Comment: select name,gender from account where fullname='" + fullname1+ "'";

Comment: @mvswetha:- Yes that will work as well. The difference lies only that in my case it is searching using a wild card match and in your case it is an exact match. Your query in question looked like you are looking for a match of pattern.

Comment: -1: With your reputation, you should definitely not recommend to concatenate variables into SQL strings like this, rather than suggesting using prepared statements and bind variables.

Comment: @LukasEder:- Thanks for pointing. Took it more of like a SQL than the programming part.